# Unable to pass a variable from one component to another-CLOSED

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an application which has 2 pages. The first is the login page where we can enter the username and on clicking the button we get routed to the home page.

The username is getting passed on via the URL and I am trying to print that username on the home page now.

This is my login.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string=''
  
  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  login()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['home',this.username])
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is my login.html file

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username">
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

And this is my home.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  
  user=''
  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) 
  { 
    activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params)=>{ this.user=params['username']})
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And this is my home.html file

```
<h1>Welcome Home {{user}}</h1>

<a routerLink='/'>Logout</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I wish to get the username after Welcome home in my home page, but for some reason, it is not happening.

Comment: I'm presuming your homepage route is declared as `{ path: 'home/:username' }`? Or are you trying to pass it as a query parameter? Also I recommend you have a look at sharing user data via a service rather than via the url - https://medium.com/@hitensharma1515/sharing-data-between-components-using-service-2d662a653a89

Comment: move activatedRoute into ngOnInit() method

Comment: @Luke.T I declared my homepage route as { path: 'home/:id' } for some reason and did not know that that the parameter should be the same as the variable name username. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke.T But why is is that { path: 'home/:id' } did not work but { path: 'home/:username'  did? Because after I did this, I tried changing the variable name but still it was working.

Comment: @AbhilekhDixit Not sure why that would happen, maybe the application hadn't compiled with the new code. But the name of the parameter in the path needs to be the same as the name you use when you retrieve it - https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/routeparams